# Codeigniter Cron Job not working in live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I create a cron job in my server it works for php file. When i try to call the controller and method of my codeigniter project it do nothing. I tried all the methods in stack overflow but nothing happen. Can anyone help me to solve this. And my code as follow

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/user_name/public_html/index.php home test
```

home is my controller name and test is my function name.

**Solution found** *See the answer below*

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found how to solve my problem. I used following code

```
php54 -f /home/{cpanel_user_name}/public_html/index.php controller_name function_name
```

Hope it may rectify someone in the future...

Comment: perfect i did the same for that

Comment: [link] http://www.asim.pk/2009/05/14/creating-and-installing-crontabs-using-codeigniter/ i use this method @Fairy

Comment: Seems similar to PHP version, so maybe for someone else would work `php55` or `php56` etc.